# My code keeps getting an error that says duplicate method setup

Tags: java, processing

I'm making a creature and need to add a moving background into it so I chose for bubbles.

On its own it works, same as the movement of the Pig. But when I combine them together it gives the error 'duplicate method setup() in my file.

Does anyone have any tips what to do?

```
Piggy myPiggy;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400) ;
  background(255) ;
  myPiggy = new Piggy();
}
void draw() {
  background(255) ;
  myPiggy.display();

}
void mouseDragged() {
  myPiggy.mouseSmoved(mouseX, mouseY);

}

void setup() {
Bubble[] bubbles = new Bubble[300];

  size(640, 360);
  for (int i = 0; i < bubbles.length; i++) {
    bubbles[i] = new Bubble(random(60));
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  for (int i = 0; i < bubbles.length; i++) {
    bubbles[i].ascend();
    bubbles[i].display();
    bubbles[i].top();
  }
}
 
class Piggy {
  float pgX= 0 ;
  float pgY= 0 ;
  int stX = 0 ;
  int stY = 0 ;
  color earColor;
  color faceColor;
  
  Piggy() {
    stX = width / 2;
    stY = height / 2;
  }

  void display () {
    //ears
    fill(255,192,203) ;
    noStroke() ;
    ellipse(stX-90, stY-70, 60, 100) ;
    ellipse(stX+90, stY-70, 60, 100) ;
    fill(stX-90, stY-70, 40, 80) ;
    fill(stX+90, stY-70, 40, 80) ;

    // face
    fill(255,192,203) ;
    ellipse(stX, stY, 250, 220);

    // eyes
    fill(255) ;
    circle(stX-60, stY-30, 40) ;
    circle(stX+60, stY-30, 40) ;
    // pupil
    fill(0) ;
    circle(stX-60, stY-25, 15);
    circle(stX+60, stY-25, 15);

    // nose
    fill(253, 89, 157) ;
    ellipse(stX, stY+20, 60, 50) ;
    fill(253, 144, 214) ;
    noStroke() ;
    circle(stX-15, stY+20, 20) ;
    circle(stX+15, stY+20, 20) ;

    //mouth
    fill(255) ;
    noStroke() ;
    arc(stX, stY+60, 50, 40, 0, PI) ;
  }

  void mouseSmoved(int x, int y) {
    stX = x;
    stY = y;
    
  }
}


class Bubble {

  float x;
  float y;
  float diameter;
  float yspeed;

  Bubble(float tempD) {
    x = random(width);
    y = height;
    diameter = tempD;
    yspeed = random(0.5, 2.5);
  }

  void ascend() {
    y = y - yspeed;
    x = x + random(-2,2);
  }

  void display() {
    stroke(0);
    noFill();
    //fill(127,100);
    ellipse(x, y, diameter, diameter);
  }

  void top() {
    if (y < -diameter/2) {
      y = height+diameter/2;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do people keep posting the same answer to this, is this a easy solution for bots?

Answer (score 1):

You have the method setup() two times, to fix the problem you can just rename one of the methods and if you don't want to do that you can just add a parameter to one of the setups `void setup(int p){the code}`

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring setup twice. There are multiple solutions to this:
1: Remove one of the setups.
2: Overload the method. Overloading a method allows you to have multiple methods with the same name, but requires them to have a different amount of parameters. To do this, simply give one of the setups a parameter.
3: Rename one of the setups.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using [Processing](https://processing.org/). In that case as was pointed out the main file in Processing can have only one `setup()` method. A simple solution is to merge their method bodies into a single setup and remove the second one, like so

```
void setup() {
  size(400, 400) ;
  background(255) ;
  myPiggy = new Piggy();

  Bubble[] bubbles = new Bubble[300];

  // You cannot have two size() calls, pick one above or this one
  //size(640, 360);

  for (int i = 0; i < bubbles.length; i++) {
    bubbles[i] = new Bubble(random(60));
  }
}
```

Please note that does not cover other aspects of your code you are trying to merge. For example, you'd need to merge`draw()` to display your Piggy as well as the bubbles.

Answer (score 0):

You've two setup() methods in your code. There should be one setup() method. If the code in both functions is useful, merge both in one and the error should go.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have two methods in your code named `setup()`

```java
Piggy myPiggy;

void setup() {    // <------------ HERE
  size(400, 400) ;
  background(255) ;
  myPiggy = new Piggy();
}
void draw() {
  background(255) ;
  myPiggy.display();

}
void mouseDragged() {
  myPiggy.mouseSmoved(mouseX, mouseY);

}

void setup() {   // <------------ HERE
Bubble[] bubbles = new Bubble[300];

  size(640, 360); //<-- this must be the first line in a setup
  for (int i = 0; i < bubbles.length; i++) {
    bubbles[i] = new Bubble(random(60));
  }
}
```

You need to rename or edit your code or delete one [`setup()`](https://processing.org/reference/setup_.html) to proceed.

ALSO, `size(x,y)` must be the first line in the setup unless you're using [`settings()`](https://processing.org/reference/settings_.html) to initialize `size()` with a variable.